# how to compare two custom dates in powershell v2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to compare 2 custom dates. Am trying check if variables hold date1 is lessthan date2, if so, report saying date1 is older date.

I getting both dates from a. date1 from log file and date2 from application itself

now, both date1 and date2 are in required format ie,

```
$Date1 = Tue,Aug 16, 2016 12:40:03
$Date2 = Mon,Aug 22, 2016 16:33:02
```

my next step is compare these 2 dates and report if date1 is older date compare to Date2, which I don't know how to proceed.. Any help/ideas is much appreciated.

Thanks to Pete and Ansgar Wiechers

updated working Code :

```
$Date1DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Date1,'ddd,MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss',[Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture); $Date2DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Date2,'ddd,MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss',[Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture); $Date1DateTime -lt $Date2DateTime
```

Comment: `$Date1DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Date1,'ddd,MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture); $Date2DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Date2,'ddd,MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture); $Date1DateTime -lt $Date2DateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only compare date strings if the string sort order is the same as the date sort order. For instance, date strings in ISO format are comparable:

```
2016-08-16T12:40:03
2016-08-22T16:33:02
```

Date strings in your custom format are not, because `T` comes after `M`, but August 16 should actually come before August 22:

```
Tue,Aug 16, 2016 12:40:03
Mon,Aug 22, 2016 16:33:02
```

If you don't have the date strings in ISO format it's usually better to parse them into actual `DateTime` values (as [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084982/how-to-compare-two-custom-dates-in-powershell-v2-0#comment65517995_39084982) suggested), particularly if your reference value is originally a `DateTime` anyway.

```
$fmt     = 'ddd,MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

$Date1 = Get-Date $LogFileDate
$val   = (b2b.exe -readparams $param | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1) -split '='
$Date2 = [DateTime]::ParseExact($val[1], $fmt, $culture)

if ($Date1 -lt $Date2) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You probably need to fix `[CultureInfo]`, since in PowerShell v2 it is not valid type accelerator.

Comment: Thanks PetSerAI. I used [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture as mentioned by Ansgar. It worked.